# How to properly inject monolog.logger / LoggerInterface as mock in a symfony phpunit kernelTestCase

Tags: symfony, logging, phpunit

I want to test if a service call or not the correct method `$logger->info()` or `$logger->error()` in a service `MyService`.

For this, I write the following test:

```php
use App\Service\MyService;
use App\Tests\Mock\MyServiceHttpClient;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

class MyServiceTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    public function testMyServiceShouldSucceed()
    {
        self::bootKernel();
        $router = self::$kernel->getContainer()->get('router');
        $logger = $this->createMock(LoggerInterface::class);
        $logger->expects($this->never())->method('error');
        $logger->expects($this->once())->method('info');
        $myService = new MyService($logger, $router);
        $myService->someMethodIExpectToSucceed();
    }
}
```

MyService.php:

```php
namespace App\Service\MyService;

class MyService
{
    private LoggerInterface $myserviceLogger;
    private UrlGeneratorInterface $router;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $myserviceLogger, UrlGeneratorInterface $router) {
        $this->logger = $myserviceLogger;
        $this->router = $router;
}
    public function someMethodIExpectToSucceed(): void
    {
        try {
            // … some code, api calls, …
            $this->logger->info("all was ok, I want that log");
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->error("something wrong happens");
        }
    }
```

This works fine, but my service have more dependencies than just `$logger` and `$router`. So I try to find a way to first inject the mock in the kernel container, like this:

```php
        self::$kernel->getContainer()->set('myservice.logger', $logger);
        $myService = self::$kernel->getContainer()->get(MyService::class)->someMethodIExpectToSucceed();
```

But this does not seems to works. I cannot use `monolog.logger` instead of `myservice.logger` because the service is private and I don't think it's a good idea to redeclare `monolog.logger` in `services_test.yaml`. But maybe I should ?

Do you have a solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a trait, used in unit tests when I want to check what is being logged.

With this, I can create/`__construct()` all the other mock or real services I need, and create what I want to test, including `$this->log` in place of any `LoggerInterface`, then get the log records to make various assertions about it.

If I needed that regularly inside a service I would itself get from the container, I'd make something similar as a service (only available in the test environment), and wire that in as a default logger - or for specific services - via the services_test.yaml file (or in packages/test/), fetching the `TestLog` service and making whatever checks against what it had recorded as needed.

```
<?php
use Monolog\Handler\TestHandler;
use Monolog\Logger;

/**
 * Create a dummy logger that can be inspected.
 *
 * Use `$this->log` on a LoggerInterface parameter to send logs to.
 * Make assertions on the contents of `$this->testLog`.
 *
 * Examples:
 * <code>
 *  * $this->testLog->reset();      // clear the previously log messages
 *  * $this->assertCount(1, $this->testLog->getRecords(), 'Only expected 1 log     message');
 *  * $this->assertTrue($this->testLog->hasDebugThatMatches('/from the API/'));
 * </code>
 */
trait TestLog
{
    protected Logger $log;
    protected TestHandler $testLog;

    /**
     * @before
     */
    public function createTestLog(): void
    {
        $this->log = new Logger('test');
        $this->testLog = new TestHandler();
        $this->log->pushHandler($this->testLog);
    }
    // more helper/assertion methods
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you want to re-define service dynamically in test, you should define it as 'public'. This is the main purpose of services_test.yaml.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that all services are public to use in your tests you have to set

```
framework:
  test: true
```

on your test/framework.yaml